# Is there problem with token expires in 7 days when using internal test app on google workspace?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-workspace, internals

Currently we use the OAuth consent screen to create the application and are in External mode. However, the problem is that the user test can only test within 7 days because the token expires. We want to use longer so want to ask the following:

1. Is there any possible way to extend token lifetime longer?
2. We also want to switch to using google workspace so have the following questions:

- When using google workspace as internal test, is there a problem of login token expire 7 days like External test app?
- When using google workspace, is it possible to add any gmail user(private account) to the workspace to test as internal?

Answer (score 3):

[Oauth2 Experation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

Solution is to set your project to production as opposed to testing.

[image]

> When using google workspace as internal test, is there a problem of login token expire 7 days like External test app?

If you set it to internal it should not be expiring but there is a bug that last I heard google was working on. I have not heard of they fixed this yet or not.